# Is it possible to get the username from my users table and store it in progress table?

Tags: sql, oop, tkinter

I want to store the inputs of smoking questions and i have used the username as a foreign key and linked it to the progress table from the users table. However the code doesn't seem to work and the data within the progress table does not get stored. Is it possible to store the data within the progress table and store it using the username that you logged in with?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

from tkinter import ttk




class user_database():

    def __init__(self, db):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("Users.db")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        command = ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
                          (
                          fullname string, 
                          username string PRIMARY KEY,
                          password string
                          )
                          ''' 
                   )

        command2 = ('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS progress
                        (username string REFERENCES users(username),
                        weekly_cigarettes integer,
                        firsttime_smoking string,       
                        monday_smoked integer

                         )'''
                    )





        self.cursor.execute(command)
        self.connection.commit()

        self.cursor.execute(command2)
        self.connection.commit()




    def SubmitQuizInfo(self, weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO progress VALUES(?,?,?)", (weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked))
        messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "Welcome to KillSmoking")
                            




    def Register_userDatabase(self, fullname, username, password):
        if fullname == "" or username == "" or password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Please complete all required fields")
        else:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (fullname, username, password))
            self.connection.commit()
            messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "Registration complete")

    def Login_userDatabse(self, username, password):
        if username == "" or password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Please complete all required fields")
        else:
            if self.cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?", (username, password)).fetchone():
                messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "You have logged in")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Invalid username or password")
                
                
               
            

    def __del__(self):

        self.connection.close()

 
db = user_database('Users.db')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = mainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()



class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('500x500')
        self.master.title('Kill Smoking')

        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

       
        entry_name = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.username)
        entry_name.grid(row = 2, column = 4)


        entry_username = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.password)
        entry_username.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

        button1 = Button(self.master, text ="Login", command = self.login_btn)
        button1.grid(row = 10, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        button2 = Button(self.master, text ="Register")
        button2.grid(row = 11, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
 
    def login_btn(self):
        username = self.username.get()
        password = self.password.get()

        db.Login_userDatabse(username, password)

        self.login_btn = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = QuizPage(self.login_btn)


class QuizPage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('700x700')
        self.master.title('Kill Smoking')

        label_spw =  Label(self.master, text ="How many cigarettes you smoke per week (estimate)")
        label_firstsmoke =  Label(self.master, text ="When did you first start smoking")
        label_msmoked =  Label(self.master, text ="Cigarettes smoked on a Monday (estimate)")

        label_spw.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        label_firstsmoke.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
        label_msmoked.grid(row = 9, column = 1)

        startsmokinglist = [ "Less than a year ago", "Last year",
                         "2 Years ago", "3-4 Years ago",
                         "Over 5 Years ago"
                         ]

        self.spw = StringVar()
        self.startsmoking = StringVar()
        self.startsmoking.set("Please Select")
        self.msmoked = StringVar()

        entry_spw= Entry(self.master, textvariable = self.spw )
        menu_firstsmoke = OptionMenu(self.master, self.startsmoking, *startsmokinglist)
        entry_msmoked= Entry(self.master, textvariable = self.msmoked)

        entry_spw.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
        menu_firstsmoke.grid(row = 7, column = 2)
        entry_msmoked.grid(row = 9, column = 2)

        Submitbtn = Button(self.master, text = "Submit", command = self.submit)
        Submitbtn.grid(row = 60, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 40)


    def submit(self): 
        weekly_cigarettes = self.spw.get()
        firstsmoke = self.startsmoking.get()
        monday_smoked = self.msmoked.get()

        db.SubmitQuizInfo(weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked)

class regPage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('500x500')
        self.master.title('Kill Smoking')


        label = Label(self.master, text ="Registration Page")
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 4, padx = 10, pady = 10)


        self.fullname = StringVar()
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

        label_name = Label(self.master, text ="fullname")
        label_name.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        entry_name = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.fullname)
        entry_name.grid(row = 2, column = 4)

        

        label_username = Label(self.master, text ="username")
        label_username.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        entry_username = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.username)
        entry_username.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

        

        label_password = Label(self.master, text ="Password")
        label_password.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        entry_password = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.password)
        entry_password.grid(row = 4, column = 4)
        
        button2 = Button(self.master, text ="Register", command=self.registration)
        button2.grid(row = 11, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

 

    def registration(self):

        fullname = self.fullname.get()
        username = self.username.get()
        password = self.password.get()

 

        db.Register_userDatabase(fullname, username, password)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that all you want to know?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're committing your changes. Also, have you verified that your code is being called? Have you verified that the `if` statements you expect to be true are actually true? Have you verified that the variables you're inserting have the values you expect?

Comment: i need help with the if statement to check whether the entry is an integer or not

Comment: and yes could you please let me know how i could put the username from the person who is logged in, into the progress table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a complete [mcve]. Note: _not_ your complete program. Write the smallest amount of code possible that lets you enter a couple of bits of data in the UI and then save it in the database.

Comment: i have minimised it to 3 bits of data in the progress table. What should i do next?

Comment: If we can't copy and paste the code to reproduce the problem, it's going to be hard for us to help.

Comment: I have copied and pasted my entire code

Comment: Did you read my earlier comment. We definitely do _not_ want your whole code. Your job is to come up with a _minimal_ example that reproduces your problem. Based on the subject of the question, you shouldn't need more than a couple of entry widgets, a button, and the functions you've already provided. I can't imagine needing more than a dozen or two lines of code.

Comment: i have minimised it as much as possible and was able to reproduce the problem, can you help now?

Comment: The `progress` table has 4 columns, but you just provide 3 values (missing `username`) to "INSERT" statement, so the insertion will fail.  You need to pass `username` into `QuizPage`, and then pass this `username` to `db.SubmitQuizInfo()` as well.  Also you need to call `self.connection.commit()` to actually save the record into `progress` table.

Comment: How can I pass through username from the main class into the quiz page class and ensure it is the same username being passed through

Answer (score 0):

The `progress` table has 4 columns but you just provide 3 values (without `username`) to the `INSERT` SQL statement, so the insertion will fail.

You need to pass the validated `username` into `QuizPage`, and then pass this `username` to `db.SubmitQuizInfo()` as well.

Also you need to call `self.connection.commit()` to actually save the record into `progress` table.

Below is the required modified code:

```py
class user_database():
    ...
    # added username argument
    def SubmitQuizInfo(self, username, weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO progress VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (username, weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked))
        self.connection.commit() # save the change
        messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "Welcome to KillSmoking")
    ...

    def Login_userDatabse(self, username, password):
        if username == "" or password == "":
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Please complete all required fields")
        else:
            print(f'{username=}, {password=}')
            if self.cursor.execute("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?", (username, password)).fetchone():
                messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS", "You have logged in")
                return True  # better return login result
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Invalid username or password")
        return False # better return login result
    ...
```

```py
class mainWindow:
    ...
    def login_btn(self):
        username = self.username.get()
        password = self.password.get()

        if db.Login_userDatabse(username, password):
            # only show the Quiz page when user is validated
            self.login_btn = Toplevel(self.master)
            self.app = QuizPage(self.login_btn, username) # pass username to QuizPage
```

```py
class QuizPage:
    def __init__(self, master, username):
        self.master = master
        self.username = username # save the username for later use
        ...

    def submit(self):
        weekly_cigarettes = self.spw.get()
        firstsmoke = self.startsmoking.get()
        monday_smoked = self.msmoked.get()
        # pass self.username to db.SubmitQuizInfo()
        db.SubmitQuizInfo(self.username, weekly_cigarettes, firstsmoke, monday_smoked)
```